Getting error for COM excel when trying to build project in Visual Studio
Using Bitbucket as remote repo.
Created a Https token in bitbucket
When trying to clone using Visual Studio it asked for username and password. I provided with my username and for password gave the token. After sometime getting the following popup with error message :
Git failed with a fatal error.
Must specify at least one AuthenticationModes
Parameter name: modes
After closing the error popup, I saw all the files were present in the destination folder .. so tried to build the project.
When I build my project I am getting error saying

The type or namespace name 'Excel' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft.Office.Interop' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

In the .csproj file there is a statement:
<COMReference Include="Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel">

Using Visual Studio professional 2022 17.4.20.
I tried to clone the repo using sourcetree and git bash as well ..it was able to clone but after that upon trying to build the project getting the same error as

The type or namespace name 'Excel' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft.Office.Interop' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

Only I am facing this issue. no one else in the project are getting any such build error. Kindly let know..

no one else in the project are getting any such build error: If there are others working on this project, then the first thing you should have done is to ask one or more of them for assistance - this is known as teamwork.

Everyone in the project have helped me in finding a solution for the same... but still there is this issue not getting resolved

Do you have the same version of Excel (or MS Office) installed as the others?

Yes Microsoft 365 (Office)

Unfortunately, this post is missing a lot of relevant information.

The following may be of interest: https://www.mobilize.net/blog/mauricios-blog-redux

Sorry have updated the post now

You probably need to add a reference to Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.  Easiest way is to use Nuget Package Manager and add "Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel".

Ensure that the version of your MS Office Excel is the same as that of others in your team and try again.

If MS Office is not installed on your PC, install it via NuGet package in Visual Studio or download the installer in this link: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/download-office?msockid=279bd90c922766f01403c8e193a267f6

How's it going now? Have your problems been solved? @sriram srinivasan

Thanks a lot Sir ..IT person had only installed outlook and teams and not all.. so got excel and other softwares installed on my laptop.. sorry for bothering .. thanks for all your support..

Glad to know your problem was solved! If the answer was helpful, you can accept it, which will help others who have the same problem.

Firstly, ensure excel software correctly installed in your PC.
If MS Office is not installed on your PC, you can install it via NuGet packages in Visual Studio or download the installer from this link.:
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/download-office?msockid=279bd90c922766f01403c8e193a267f6
In your Visual Studio project, ensure that the COMReference part is correctly defined in your .csproj project file like this:
<ItemGroup>
  <COMReference Include="Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel">
    <Guid>{00020813-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}</Guid>
    <VersionMajor>1</VersionMajor>
    <VersionMinor>9</VersionMinor>
    <Lcid>0</Lcid>
    <WrapperTool>tlbimp</WrapperTool>
    <Isolated>false</Isolated>
  </COMReference>
</ItemGroup>


This is the same details present in the .csproj file .. thanks

All other members in my team have the following in COM reference dlls displayed as below :
ACTIVEXLib,
Microsoft.Office,
Microsoft.Office.Interop,   Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access,VSTOEE100......
And In my project COM reference : I have the following : Interop.Microsoft.Office.Core,   Interop.Microsoft.Office.Access.Dao, Interop.VSTOEE100 and its throwing error saying :
The type or namespace name 'Excel' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft.Office.Interop' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

for All other team members "Microsoft Excel 16.0 Object Library" is one of library that is checked in COM -> Add Reference popup dialog... and I dont have it in my COM reference dialog ...how and where can I find this library to install .. kindly let know
